# Unable to authenticate R-Shiny App using Azure Active Directory

Tags: r, azure, shiny, gis, raster

I am working on an R-Shiny app that is hosted on the R-Shiny platform. In this process, I need to authenticate the app, so that I can download certain files from OneDrive and use them to host the app on R-Shiny.

Due to this, I am currently using the Azure Active Directory setup to go ahead and provide for authentication on the app. The Azure refresh token should be able to go ahead and take care of that authentication process, since it would be able to refresh automatically.

I have been following the template code on this specific tutorial for using Microsoft365R with R-Shiny: [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/shiny.html#:~:text=This%20vignette%20describes%20how%20to%20incorporate%20Microsoft365R%20and,token%20Pass%20the%20token%20to%20the%20Microsoft365R%20functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/vignettes/shiny.html#:%7E:text=This%20vignette%20describes%20how%20to%20incorporate%20Microsoft365R%20and,token%20Pass%20the%20token%20to%20the%20Microsoft365R%20functions).

Currently, the issue is that my app won't load the expected plots as intended whenever I insert the code for the retrieving the azure token.

As of now, I have gone ahead and implemented the following code, in reference to the provided template.

```
library(AzureAuth)
library(AzureGraph)
library(Microsoft365R)
library(shiny)
library(httr)

tenant <- 'exampletenantID'

app <- 'exampleappID'

redirect <- " https://flashdrought.shinyapps.io/Flash_tool/"
port <- httr::parse_url(redirect)$port
options(shiny.port = if (is.null(port))
  443
  else
    as.numeric(port))

pwd <- Sys.getenv(client_passcode, "")
if (pwd == "")
  pwd <- NULL

resource <- c("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", "openid")

DateRun = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date(Sys.Date() - 2), by = 1)


ui <- fluidPage(# Application title
  titlePanel(
    title = div(
      id = "dummy",
      img(
        height = 75,
        width = 75,
        src = "FLASHlogo.png",
        #style="position:absolute;top:330px;right:35px;z-index:1000;"
      ),
      "Global Flash Drought Stress Assessment"
    )
  ),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot"),
  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(
    3,
    h4("Select a date"),
    selectInput("Date", "(yyyy-mm-dd)", choices = DateRun),
    actionButton("goButton", "Update")
  )))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  library(terra)
  library(RColorBrewer)
  library(spData)
  library(terra)
  library(tmap)
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    dataSelect = format(as.Date(input$Date), "%Y%m%d")
    
    opts <- parseQueryString(isolate(session$clientData$redirect))
    if (is.null(opts$code))
      return()
    
    tokenGet <-
      get_azure_token(
        c(
          "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All",
          "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All",
          "https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.ReadWrite.All",
          "offline_access"
        ),
        tenant,
        app,
        password = pwd,
        auth_type = "authorization_code",
        authorize_args = list(redirect_uri = redirect),
        version = 2,
        auth_code = opts$code,
        aad_host = currentHost
      )
    
    dataSelect = format(as.Date(input$Date), "%Y%m%d")
    
    od <- get_personal_onedrive()
    od$list_items()
    od$list_files()
    od$download_file(paste("Public/FDSI/fdsiRas-", dataSelect, ".tif", sep =
                             ""),
                     overwrite = TRUE)
    FDSIselect = rast(paste("fdsiRas-", dataSelect, ".tif", sep = ""))
    
    cols <- colorRampPalette(
      brewer.pal(11, 'RdYlBu'),
      space = 'Lab',
      interpolate = 'spline',
      bias = 1
    )
    mypal = cols(6)
    #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    #tmap_mode("plot")
    myMap = tm_shape(FDSIselect) +
      tm_raster(
        title = "Flash Drought Stress Index",
        palette = rev(mypal),
        style = "fixed",
        breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.71, 1),
      ) +
      tm_layout(legend.position = c("left", "bottom")) +
      tm_grid(alpha = 0.2) +
      tm_xlab("Longitude", size = 1.2) +
      tm_ylab("Latitude", size = 1.2) +
      tm_layout(
        inner.margins = 0,
        legend.text.size = 1.1,
        legend.title.size = 1.2
      ) +
      tm_shape(world) +
      tm_sf(alpha = 0.25)
    
    print(myMap)
    file.remove(paste("fdsiRas-", dataSelect, ".tif", sep = ""))
    
  })
  
}
```

This is the expected output.
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kxw8.png)

However, when I run the above code, I simply get a blank screen. Any advise and guidance would be appreciated Thanks!